# ExtJS equivalent of JQuery's children?

Tags: jquery, extjs

I tried implementing the children function in ExtJS using select("~ *"), it just didnt work well.

I just want ExtJS to return me a set of immediate child node and ignore all the nodes under child nodes.

```
<div>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
</div>
```

In fact I just want the number of immediate childs. If I get the select right, I can do a getCount() on the CompositeElement.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can id the parent, then you could do something like this to get the children:

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Define a function like this:

```
    function getChildren(parentId) {
      var kids = Ext.get(parentId).select('*');
      kids = kids.filter(function(el) {
            return el.parent().id == parentId
      });
      return kids;
    }
```

In your example, `getChildren('mydiv').getCount()` will return 3.

Comment: hey, you are awesome :) I know it might be a little too much to ask but I do hope you can answer it. I still can't figure out how we can select a class element in ExtJS like Jquery can go easily with $(".myclass"). Ext.get() is only for id. 

Thanks again :)

Comment: Try `Ext.query('.myClass')[0];` to select your DOM element by class

Answer (score 1):

> I tried implementing the children function in ExtJS using select("~
>   *"), it just didnt work well.

I believe what you are looking for is "> *".  In ExtJs you could do:

```
var children = Ext.get("myDiv").query("> *");
```

with

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </span>
</div>
```

The variable children will now be an array of direct descendant HTMLElements (in this case 3 spans).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could provide a representation of the desired DOM elements that would be selected, however, if I understand your question correctly I think you want to use `Ext.Element`.

From `Ext.CompositeElement`, you have access to all of the methods from `Ext.Element`. Using `Ext.Element.select`, `Ext.Element.parent`, `Ext.Element.query`, `Ext.Element.next`, and so on, you should have access to whatever element you want.

See:
http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.fx.html#cls-Ext.Element

Servus,

-bn

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the number of children, you can simple use

```
Ext.select('div span').getCount();
```

It returns 3 in your example.